# Compiling errors occur while convert a project to AspectJ project with AspectJ eclipse 3.4 plugin, ajdt2.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, aspectj, ajdt

Hey,
I wanna to add AOP to my web project. I download ajdt2.0.1 for eclipse 3.4.1. But when I convert this project to AspectJ projects, I got so many compile errors which shouldn't occur. Such as "XXXDAO cannot be resolved", etc. When I remove AspectJ Capability, everything goes well. Does anyone meet this problems?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I'd recommend upgrading to Eclipse 3.6.  3.4 is no longer supported.  Second, I need some more information.  Such as what are the complete error messages and what is on your classpath.

Comment: code: System.out.println("Login user：" + userID); 
I get error "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote".
code :for (UserAllActionBean bean : list),
error: "Syntax error on token ",", ; expected"
My classpath contains:
Tomcat6.0 library
AspectJ Runtime Library which is aspectj 1.6.6.
JRE 6.0.
WebApp Library.
Btw, now I am working with eclipse 3.3 and AJDT 1.5.3, AJ works fine.

Comment: And all these compile errors are so mysterious, all java source files are compiled successfully when I remove AspectJ Capability. And the same project can be converted successfully wtih Eclipse 3.3 and AJDT 1.5.3 .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it by set ajc option with "-encoding UTF-8". That's mysterious, cause the encoding of eclipse is exactly utf-8. Does that mean ajc use my OS default encoding?

Comment: Hi Xiaowl, I also encountered this issue. Could you please tell me how do I set ajc option with "-encoding UTF-8" in eclipse? Thanks!