# Compile errors in converting Android project to AspectJ

Tags: android, adt, aspectj

I got a lot of compile errors (500+) when converting my Android project into AspectJ project. Most of the errors are like "xxx cannot be resolved to a type"

As this page suggests, this might be an encoding issue: [Compiling errors occur while convert a project to AspectJ project with AspectJ eclipse 3.4 plugin, ajdt2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363814/compiling-errors-occur-while-).... But I am not able to figure out how to set this ajc option in Eclipse.

I am using ADT.

Could anyone help me out? Just let me know if you need other information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem.

Because I am on Mac, ADT is using some weird encoding for text files. I just need to tell ADT to use UTF-8, which is also used by AspectJ compiler.

These compile errors were caused by the fact that ADT and AspectJ compiler were using different encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to execute this on command line: ajc -encoding UTF-8

If ajc was not recognized as a command, please add it to the Path.

I found these links, they could be helpful:
http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg07331.html
http://osdir.com/ml/java.aop.aspectj.general/2007-01/msg00034.html
[How to change the defaults system java encode form in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661935/how-to-change-the-defaults-system-java-encode-form-in-windows)

Please, let me know if you resolved your issue.

Carlos

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I've already installed AJDT in Eclipse, but in order for me to execute ajc, I think I need to install AspectJ compiler as well, is it correct? After I install AspectJ compiler, I enter "ajc -encoding UTF-8", but encounter this error "[error] no sources specified". How should I resolve this? What kind of source it is asking? Thx!!

Comment: Sorry for not answer it on time. I see you found the exact cause of the problem, I'm glad I may helped a bit. :D